# How do I enable GregTech Plate recepies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Gregtech changed a lot of recepies back in 1.5.2. (well, he always seems to be changing stuff but this is the specific time that I noticed *this* change)

One of the changes that I noticed was his introduction of the Hammers, and most recepies that previously used Ingots now used Plates. My new server does not have this pre-set and I'm unable to find in the configs where I can enable these harder recepies.

I am running TPPI the recommended version listed in the FTB Launcher. (pack code MegaSharkPunch)

I checked back to Unhinged (what i used to run, that had these recepies) and the options were located in the dynamic config, but the new gregtech I'm running in TPPI doesn't have them... did Greg remove this feature perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing a config somehow. I'd grab at least the GregTech folder from the [TTPI GitHub repository](https://github.com/TPPI-Dev/TestPackPleaseIgnore/tree/master/config) just to be sure. `DynamicConfig.cfg` is there in that folder on the repository, and does disable the IC2 forgehammer by default.